# Getting values from multiple GTK spinboxes

Tags: python, gtk

Image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4900888/GUI.png
Source and UI is in comments, due to "New-user-limiations"

I'm sorry if I've totally misunderstood what this site is about, but I have a problem.

When the button in the lower left corner is pressed, I want to get the values from the three spinboxes and save the as variables for use in a function that is triggered by the button.
I'm really blank as to how you would do this.
Any help is appreciated, and additional information can be supplied if it needs to.

EDIT:
I am using Python, and Gtk+ through Glade.

PS:
Does Stack Overflow have any code sharing site prefferences such as pastebin and so on?

Comment: This seems to be some manner of C, I am using Python, and (I think), Gtk+.
I'll add this information to the first post.

Comment: Can you please supply the code you're using to create the interface so we can pick it apart and see what's what.

Comment: Source:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4900888/Deadliner.py
UI:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4900888/Mockup.glade

The UI is made using Glade, so you'll probably need Glade to make any sense of it.

Comment: It seems you've selected an answer, but you've not yet solved your problem.  One way this site works is that unanswered (aka unsolved) questions get more attention.  You generally want to wait until you've gotten the answer that solves your problem before clicking that check outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: with the spin button's `get_value_as_int()` method.

I suspect, however, that your actual problem is getting a reference to the spin button to call `get_value_as_int()` on. From [your code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4900888/Deadliner.py) I see that you are using `gtk.Builder` to build your UI.

### Accessing widgets

Keeping a reference to specific widgets in `Handler` instance:

```
    handler = Handler()
    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    ...
    # Store references to widgets in `handler`
    for widget_name in ('sbtn_days', 'sbtn_hours', 'sbtn_minutes'):
        setattr(handler, widget_name, builder.get_object(widget_name))
    # The above is equivalent to the following:
    handler.sbtn_days = builder.get_object('sbtn_days')
    ...

    # In signal handling code:
    days = self.sbtn_days.get_value_as_int()
```

Or you can keep a reference in to `builder` in your `Handler` instance:

```
    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    handler = Handler()
    handler.builder = builder
    ...

    # In signal handler code:
    sbtn_days = self.builder.get_object('sbtn_days')
    days = sbtn_days.get_value_as_int()
```

### Notes

In the code above,

- I assumed that your spin button for days is named `sbtn_days`. Adjust as necessary.
- I only demonstrated accessing `sbtn_days` and its value. The other buttons can be accessed in a similar way.

P.S. There are a bunch of other problems with your code keeping it from being "good".

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can get this to work.
Am I correct in assuming that I don't need to edit the UI file, save for possible name changes?

Comment: Also am I reading this correctly? 
The full line for getting the value would be something like `(days = self.Handler().Gtk.Builder().get_object('sbtn_days').get_value_as_int()`

Comment: @Dorako: Yes, no changes to your UI file is necessary. The "full line" depends on the approach above that you've chosen. From within a signal handler function it would either be `self.sbtn_days.get_value_as_int()` or `self.builder.get_object('sbtn_days').get_value_as_int().

Comment: `class Handler:
    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    handler = Handler()
    handler.builder = builder

    #pressing the "Create Deadline" button activates this
    def onCreateDeadline(self, button):
        global fU
        global sU
        global has_deadline

        has_deadline = True

        #Fetch the value of sbtn_days
        sbtn_days = self.builder.get_object('sbtn_days')
        days = sbtn_days.get_value_as_int()`

Did I add this the wrong place?

NameError: Name "Handler" is not defined

EDIT: Whoa, no newlines or indentation in comments, I guess.

Comment: Post your code somewhere it can be edited and paste link here, please.

Comment: Seems I need more help. The best results I can get is an `AttributeError: "NoneType" object has no attribute "get_value_as_int()"`. On which lines should the different parts be placed? I'll see if I can make sense of it, once it works.

Comment: Do you know a good place? I uploaded it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/GiJ3RWyd)

Comment: Mail it to me at GMail: wrleibbrandt